# Process.env Variables Not Available Outside of Function During Jest Testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I ran into an issue where my imported `env` variables are not available outside of function scope and I wonder if this is an intentional design or am I doing something wrong

For example my setup looks like this

`/src/index.test.js`

```
//require config
const config = require('../config.json');
const myFunc = require('./index.js');

beforeEach(async () =>
{
   //set env vars
     process.env = Object.assign(process.env, config);
})

test('sample', async () =>
{
   //call function
   await myFunc();

  expect(somethingMeaninful).toBeCalledTimes(1);
})
```

And then my actual code looks like this

`src/index.js`

```
const myVar = process.env.myVar

console.log(process.env.myVar) //<= will be undefined

async function myFunc()
{
   console.log(process.env.myVar) //<= will show my value from config.json file

    return somethingMeaninful();
}

exports.myFunc = myFunc();
```

So since `myVar` is declared outside of function it is undefined.
I tried doing console.log() on process.env as a whole inside and outside my func and outside it would have all the default values but inside it would have defaults + my config values as well. Really confused by how and why this happens. Those variables are not undefined when I run my code normally but are undefined during testing...

This link mentions this issue here as well
[github vue testing issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/193#issuecomment-633146757)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Apparently my `jest.config.js` file was never being read. And because of this none of the `setupFiles` or `setupFilesAfterEnv` were running either.

It was because I had my `jest.config.js` in `<rootDir>/jest` because I had in the nested folder called `jest` it never ran. Moving it out of there into root fixed my issues. And all of my files are being ran as necessary